# In a Tekton Pipeline what do you need to modify to make the pipeline skip a test, if that unit test is taking too long? Without the pipeline failing?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, tekton

In the Tekton documentation (https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelineruns/#configuring-a-failure-timeout) it specifies that you can have a " timeout" field for a particular task. However the pipeline will fail. Is there any way to set a condition where a task/test that is taking longer than 1 hour will simply skip the test without making the pipeline fail? I'm new to Tekton so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!